# CSS form buttons

Tags: button, css

I'm looking for a good way to implement reusable buttons in CSS on my forms. The requirements:
- Separate image and text (text is in many languages)
- Rollover effects
- Plays nicely cross browser
- No javascript (if possible)
- Rounded corners

Whats the best way to do this? Years ago I was using the sliding doors technique, but this seems out of date now. Would you use CSS3 with a fallback for older browsers? Any particularly well thought of techniques out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use css sprites for this. You can find out about them here:
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

It is basically a way to make one large image that has all states of buttons(normal, hover, selected). The benefit is it is one http request and you don't see a flicker the first time a hover occurs. If you use this route, the css background property will be the image. You can then use text-align and line-height to center the text that you want to place over the image.

Answer (score 4):

Jquery UI buttons are AWESOME.  They're fully tested, completely compliant, and really look great.  With one line of code, you can have a fully styled button in no time flat.  Here's the thing--they can be executed without Jquery (go figure)

[First, the tut](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

So, the standard method is to build an element (a, button, input) with an id and set it as a button in Jquery like this:`$('#element').button()`

However, if you do it in the manner that the tutorial shows, you just have to add some classes to an element to get a similar effect.  So, to make a button out of an a tag, it would just be

```
<a href="" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Button</a>
```

In this example, there's no need to set the button with the jQuery button declaration...you're doing it by style only.  With the flexibility to style so many different type of elements, it opens up a ton of doors.

You would have to have the Jquery UI css loaded, which offers the added benefit of ThemeRoller, which can style elements on the page with a simple change of a file.  It's really a great way to "theme" a site that has to change branding in a hurry, which has made custom themed apps my company puts out extremely profitable.

Comment: I read through the tut and it left me totally confused, I have to use the jQuery UI CSS styles right? Plus I would need to load jQuery UI?

Comment: Alex, yes, you would have to use JQuery UI styles.  Download Jquery UI with an appropriate style for your page.  Open the zip file, take only the CSS folder.  You'll have to include the css file in the CSS folder in the page you want to use buttons.  Then, any element you want to add the styling to should have the classes from above added.    Alternatively, you could go all Jquery and call the button with the first method I described, which adds rollover styling.  It's a little imposing at first, but the possibilities are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

This library, [Nifty Corners Cubed](http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html) uses Javascript but is a fairly clean way to round div tags links, etc.  It is tough to find a reusable solution without using a sliding doors derived technique.  Otherwise you stuck making none-resuable buttons that have to fit to your size.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at PIE http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score -1):

A sprite is a great option and I do use them from time to time.

Personally I don't mind if my websites aren't identical in all browsers and I go the CSS class route. I keep in mind what is and isn't supported by various browsers and if there is an element that needs to be a certain way I will double check with [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) for compatibility.

The main benefit the keeps me using CSS/CSS3 classes is if something changes it is done quickly by text in a single file, if need be I can do a quick change from a 10 year old computer with a dial-up connection (if they still exist) and no imaging software. 
Where the advantage of a sprite is they are supported across all browsers and they will look identical (more or less). [SpriteMe](http://spriteme.org/) is a bookmarklet that I have heard of to help with sprites if you decide to go down this path.

I see this as a what do you prefer matter... these questions are what I ask myself when making this type of decision:
How often will it change? Big or small changes? Will it be a complete redesign job if it changes? What do you already know? How much time are you willing to spend learning something that you may not know? What does your gut say for this project?

I hope this can help you.